# Setting up HTTPS on NGINX Server

Tags: node.js, nginx, ssl, https, nginx-config

I'm trying to setup NGINX for HTTPS.
I have a node app and NGINX acting as a reverse proxy.
However once setup and trying to access my website I get "too many redirects" error,
I think something is wrong with my NGINX configuration, any help?
[image]

Comment: Post your config as text and not image.

Comment: Would it matter?

Comment: Complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then you know why it matters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that proxy_pass should have been https not http.
It basically kept redirecting me to http back and forth.